# 2 Links in One Anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, anchor

I have a `<ul><li><a>` structure that is stylized very specifically and has 9 elements separated in 3 columns. I want to add another item without making a 4th column so the solution I'm considering is having 2 links in one 'slot'.

The problem with this is that the `<ul><li><a>` is structured such that adding an `<a>` will automatically create another slot (vertically).

I'm hoping not to have to recreate the entire structure from scratch in order to accommodate this change, so I'm trying to come up with a hack.

I KNOW THIS IS UGLY AND WEIRD but it does make for an interesting problem atleast...

I tried doing:

```
<a href="link1.html">link1 <span onclick="location.href ='link2.html'">link2</span></a>
```

But that doesn't work - I also tried with jQuery but that didn't work either. Is there a workaround/hack here or do I have to restructure the entire list?

Comment: Can you give a full example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to [stop propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) of the click to the parent anchor element. Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this from an `onclick` attribute.

Comment: @Blazemonger Yes there is. `<span onclick="myFunction(event);">` and call `event.stopPropagation()` inside the function.

Comment: @mhodges I wasn't being clear. I meant *without* using a separate `<script>` function, but yes, that should work.

Comment: I have this: 

`<a href="link1.html">link1 <span onclick="handleClick(ev)">link2</span></a>`

with the function being: 

  `function handleClick(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
}`

Tried inline and linking thru an external .js file and it still navigates to `link1.html` ... It seems like the click is never being registered by the `<span>`

Comment: @SamYoungNY You have to call it `event` in the `onclick` attribute. It does not know what `ev` is

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and easy way to have the `a` and `span` elements take you to different links.  (I commented out the actual link and used alerts instead, since the links won't load in the frame anyway.)

```js
function goToLink(e, that) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (that.tagName.toUpperCase() == "A") {
    // if anchor was clicked
    alert("1st link");
    //window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  }
  else {
    // if span was clicked
    alert("2nd link");
    //window.location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="goToLink(event, this);">link1 <span onclick="goToLink(event, this);">link2</span></a>
```

The `stopPropagation()` call prevents the first link from loading when the second link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#link2').click(function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    location.href = $('#link2').attr('data-href')
  }, 10)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="link1.html">link1 <span id='link2' data-href="link2.html">link2</span></a>
```

Comment: You should use code that accurately represents the original question.

Comment: @Blazemonger It is really weird when your edit is updated without my approval :)

Comment: may be I got the question wrong.. I thought he wanted two hrefs..thats why he added an extra `span`. He could just add it as another attribute, may be `href2` to the same `a` tag

Comment: @MrLister okay.. but what is the point in adding `href` to span?? So I proposed it is similar to adding another attribute `href2` to `a` tag